# find an equation of the plane tangent to the surface at the point (1,3*Pi)

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the plane tangent to the surface at the point $\left(1,3\pi\right).\quad z =x^{3y\sin\left(y\right)}$

I got $z=1$. Is 1 an equation or I did wrong?

Comment: Hi new user! $\color{blue}{\large{\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}}$ Don't worry about it now but you might like to know that we use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$) $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, but it's not clear that you're correct for the right reasons.

First, when $x = 1$ and $y = 3 \pi$, you can get $z = 1$, so the point $(1, 3 \pi, 1)$ lies on your surface. But that's not necessarily the equation for the tangent plane.

The tangent plane to your surface is spanned by the vectors

$$
\matrix{[1& 0& 
\frac{\partial z} {\partial x} (1, 3\pi, 1)]}
$$
and
$$
\matrix{[0& 1& 
\frac{\partial z} {\partial y} (1, 3\pi, 1)]}.
$$

You'll need to compute these, and their cross product, to get a normal vector $(A, B, C)$, from which you can find the tangent-plane equation, which will be 
$$
A(x - 1) + B(y - 3\pi) + C(z - 1) = 0.
$$

And I'm hoping that you did exactly this, found that the two partials were both zero at the point $(x, y) = (1, 3\pi)$, and then found that $(A, B, C) = (0, 0, \pm 1)$ (depending on which order you used for the cross product). That then leads to

$$
0(x-1) + 0(y - 3\pi) + 1(z-1) = z - 1 = 0, 
$$
i.e., 
$$
z = 1.
$$

Comment: is A,B,C = 0,0,-1?

Comment: Yes; original answer modified to reflect that.